# Product is not displaying into Magento ver. 2.4.2

Tags: php, magento, magento2

We are using  Magento ver. 2.4.2 version and products are not displaying into the front end side.

We also run following commands but still products are not displaying into the frontend.

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:clean

At present, all existing  products has "Default stock 0" under the "Salable Quantity" column.

Can anyone know us what can be an issue? Is there any solution?
Which process should I need to do?

Please advice

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of things you need to check for product to display on the frontend. Also make sure to that settings are not overridden on store view level:

1. Enable Product: Yes
2. Stock Status: In Stock
3. Categorie: Category added
4. Visibility: Catalog, Search
5. Product in Websites: Website(s) checked

Also make sure the cron is configured so reindex will be running. You can also run manually from command line: `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`.
You can see status: System > Tools > Index Management.

And make sure to clear cache: System > Cache Management.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things:

1. Make sure elastic search working properly.
   Installation guide `https://jmsoni.wordpress.com/2020/09/18/how-to-install-elasticsearch-in-ubantu/`
2. Please check configuration of "Shared Catalog"

Don't forget to clear cache after change of any configuration.